# How to Detect the OS in C at running time

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

I know it isn't simple, I've been researching it for a while, and now I'm almost sure that there's no completely safe way of doing so. But here is it.
I looking for a way of knowing which is the Operating System that my application is running on. Up to now, I got this:

```
#if defined(__WIN64__) || defined(__WIN64) || defined(WIN64)
    #define NLF_OS_WINDOWS
    #define NLF_OS_64BITS
#elif defined(__WIN32__) || defined(__WIN32) || defined(WIN32)
    #define NLF_OS_WINDOWS
    #define NLF_OS_32BITS
#elif defined(unix) || defined(__unix__) || defined(__unix)
    #define NLF_OS_UNIX
    #if defined(__APPLE__)
        #define NLF_OS_APPLE
        #define NLF_OS_BITS_UNIDENTIFIED
        #include <TargetConditionals.h>
        #if TARGET_OS_IPHONE && TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
            #define NLF_OS_SIMULATOR
        #elif TARGET_OS_IPHONE
            #define NLF_OS_IPHONE
        #else
            #define NLF_OS_OSX
        #endif
    #elif defined(__linux__) || defined(__linux) || defined(linux)
        #define NLF_OS_LINUX
        #if defined(i386) || defined(__i386) || defined(__i386__)
            #define NLF_OS_32BITS
        #elif defined(amd64)  || defined(__amd64) || defined(__amd64__)
            #define NLF_OS_64BITS
        #endif
    #elif defined(__FreeBSD__) || defined(__FreeBSD) || defined(FreeBSD)
        #define NLF_OS_FREEBSD
        #if defined(i386) || defined(__i386) || defined(__i386__)
            #define NLF_OS_32BITS
        #elif defined(amd64)  || defined(__amd64) || defined(__amd64__)
            #define NLF_OS_64BITS
        #endif
    #endif
#else
    #define NLF_OS_UNIDENTIFIED
    #define NLF_OS_BITS_UNIDENTIFIED
#endif
```

It has already helped, but it only tells me what is the system when I'm compiling the application. But, since I want to cross-compile what I'm doing, it would be tremendously useful if I could provide to the app a way to know which is the current running system. Get it?

May be I may use the libraries sys/"something" (like sys/types.h and sys/stat.h) to do some ugly stuff, but I barely know any of those things.

PS.: A C++ solution isn't exactly what I want, but at this high I'm on it ^^"

Comment: If you're crosscompiling, you should already know, before you compile, onto which platform you're crosscompiling to. So, pass that as a preprocessor symbol, that's it.

Comment: technically, pre processing stage isn't runtime, this would be at compile time

Comment: @self Even not technically...

Comment: it's not like you could take an .exe compiled for msdos and run it directly on (say) an OSX system. that will just never happen, so a run-time OS check is rather pointless/useless. can't run the check unless the executable has been compiled for that particular OS in the first place. OS **VERSION** checking is another matter... that's relatively easy to do, and pretty much every OS will have some kind of a syscall to report version info

Comment: maybe he means runtime as in the time he "runs" his compiler

Comment: No, no. Sorry the inconvenience.
I'm not crosscompiling yet, but I intend to. Still need to study it ^^"

Comment: On a crosscompiling point of view, why would a runtime check/flag help you?

Comment: Use `config.guess` as is used in GNU autoconf, but self-contained: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/config.git

Comment: let me tell a exemple:
I want to creat a app that runs in windows and linux. I'll crosscompile it from linux to windows. When my app is running therer, I want it to know that it's on windows.
But, it sound that the crosscompiler already take care of the symbols... I did know that ^^

Comment: @LeonardoDaVinci You can't. Period. Switch to Java for this kind of stuff.

Comment: Short running the other version through an emulator, you already know which OS the program is running under because you had to compile a different executable for each OS. I join many others in not seeing the point of a runtime version.

Comment: Wanting to detect the OS is often a sign of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Why do you think you need to know the OS? Are you assuming that some OS's will provide certain functionality and others will not?  Check for that functionality directly instead.

Comment: I know, but in this 'case, it's not. What I'm really trying to make is a cross platform framework. This knowlege would be more userful to the application running over the fremework than to the framework itself, I think.
To do stuff like, minimizing battery spent... stuff like that.
But I already have my answer, thanks =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just finally answering this question.

The answer is: you don't need to. I've noticed that. The defines already works just fine. If you're compiling a C code for another platform, the cross compiler will take care of redefining de defines, so your system will always know what system is if you use the preprocessor directives.

But if for, some reason you really need it, you'll have to do ugly stuff. Like use a *system("uname -a > my_file");* and then reading my_file content, and then try another command if this one do not works.

Mainly, you don't need it =)

Comment: I don't know why people gave me some many down votes :'(
That was a valid and interesting question, but with no easy answer. Just because it seems useless? ^^" come'on its not ^^ I've learned something =)

Comment: 'some many down votes'??  _No_, only one down vote and two up votes (including the one on your answer).